# What should be used here? "don't" or "won't"?

Tags: grammar, difference

The song anything could happen by Ellie Goulding has these lyrics:

> cover your eyes so you don't know the secret

https://genius.com/amp/Ellie-goulding-anything-could-happen-lyrics

shouldn't it be *won't* instead of *don't*?

Answer (score 1):

- **You won't know until I tell you** [at some future point.]
- **You don't know [now] because I haven't told you [yet].

That song would have more standard English, if it had said:

- Cover your eyes so [that] you don't **find out** the secret.

so [that] expresses a purpose. It is often used with a modal **but not always.**

- Please **don't move Johnny** so the bees **don't sting you** [now] or won't sting  you [at some future point].

For a general statement, the present simple is fine. But so is the future. It depends on what the speaker wishes to say.

[explanation of so as purpose](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/8-9.html)

Comment: in this bees example the one in present simple sounds okay. the future one sounds weird. cause in my native language so(as conjunction) is not followed by will whether it's for present or future. that's what confused me